# How to understand Auto layout in Swift UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am struggling with auto layout. I am trying to build a simple interface as the following:

**Layout**

[image]

But the problem is when I run the app on different devices something is always messed up. So far what I have done is:

- I tried putting each in separate stack view - one stack for the logo, text and image, one for text fields and one for button. - didn't manage to do it.
- I tried all possible separations in views, stack different combinations all types of constraints couldn't get it to display properly on every device.

The closest I got the get it working was with all the controls smashed really close to each other.

How can I understand this auto layout?  read all results from Google and tried everything from there, but still something is missing.

### Edit

This is my latest attempt which kind-a works but smashes the buttons on small views

[image: constraints]

Comment: Without knowing specifically what's going wrong and what your constraints are set to for the problematic views it's hard to give a specific answer. However if you want a link to a resource that is helpful in understanding layout and constraints I recommend this one: https://www.raywenderlich.com/17344826-uikit-layout

Comment: I like Kramer's comment. Help us to help you by adding some code to the question (tap edit to add). There are many different ways this could be done. By showing us what you've tried we can get an insight into which concepts you have grasped, and where you may need more help.

Comment: Okay, I added the constraints this raywenderlich course looks nice but its quite expensive and right now due to the pandemic I am left with no job :)

Comment: The site has a lot of free stuff available. As does hackingwithswift.com. The important thing is to start. Later, when you can afford it, you can consider more options. 

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I took a stab at it. Obviously, you can achieve this in many different ways, but I'll name two.

First is using the Visual Format Language.  I know it's an archaic tool and not many people are a fan of it, but when it comes to displaying a list of items in a row that requires a lot of subtle adjustments in their spacing to your liking, I find it to be rather concise. And, best of all, you can combine it with anchor layouts:

```swift
let logoRenderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 130, height: 130))
var ovalImages: [UIImage] = []
for _ in 0..<2 {
    let temp = logoRenderer.image { (_) in
        let o = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 130, height: 130))
        UIColor.orange.setFill()
        o.fill()
    }
    ovalImages.append(temp)
}

// first oval
let ovalImage1 = UIImageView(image: ovalImages[0])
ovalImage1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(ovalImage1)

// label
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "TEXT"
label.backgroundColor = .clear
label.textAlignment = .center
label.layer.borderWidth = 1
label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(label)

// second oval
let ovalImage2 = UIImageView(image: ovalImages[1])
ovalImage2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(ovalImage2)

// 3 text fields
let containerView = UIStackView()
containerView.axis = .vertical
containerView.distribution = .fillEqually
containerView.spacing = 10
let list = [0, 1, 2]
for index in list.indices {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.placeholder = "Text field \(index + 1)"
    textField.textAlignment = .center
    textField.backgroundColor = .white
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    containerView.addArrangedSubview(textField)
}
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(containerView)

// button
let button = UIButton()
button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(button)

let views: [String: Any] = ["oval1": ovalImage1, "label": label, "oval2": ovalImage2, "cv": containerView, "button": button]
let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-50-[oval1(130)]-20-[label(50)]-20-[oval2(130)]-20-[cv(200)]-50-[button(50)]", metrics: nil, views: views)

let l = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
let horizontalConstraints = [
    ovalImage1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
    label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    ovalImage2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
    containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: l.leadingAnchor),
    containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: l.trailingAnchor),
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalConstraints + horizontalConstraints)
```

Second way is to use the stack view for the entire list of elements and use [setCustomSpacing(_:after:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/2866023-setcustomspacing) to adjust the spacing granularly.

```swift
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: arrangedSubviews)
self.view.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.alignment = .center
stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
```

You append all the elements into `arrangedSubviews` to instantiate the stack view. It's important to note that `.fillProportionally` needs the intrinsic size for each element so if the layout doesn't look right, make sure you implement that.

[image]

Comment: I just tried the first approach and on iPod touch simulator the text fields are going out of the screen

Comment: `layoutMarginsGuide` is only available for iOS 9.0+. Try without it.

Comment: tried it also on iPhone 8, iPhone SE and all the others with smaller screens, the layout is cut

Comment: What iOS are they using? Try with `containerView.alignment = .center`.  Or with `self.view.leadingAnchor` and `self.view.trailingAnchor`.

Comment: all of them are above iOS 12, just tried what you suggested but the content is still cut

Comment: have you deactivated all the pre-existing constraints from your Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes this is on a complete new controller

Comment: When you say "the text fields are going out of the screen", are they not centered horizontally, crossing the upper/lower edge, or both?

Comment: https://imgur.com/oFu3UkI this is how it looks like, the button is cut off screen